How to prevent popup cards from affecting the color of other cards when blurred
I create a Popup like with blurred background like this 
As you can see the popup card is suffering from other colors inside the card. I want the popup tag to be white and separated from the background. Here my code :


function toggle() {
  var blur = document.getElementById('blur');
  blur.classList.toggle('active')
  var popup = document.getElementById('popup');
  popup.classList.toggle('active')
}
.container#blur.active {
  filter: blur(20px);
  pointer-events: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#popup {
  position: fixed;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -20%);
  width: 600px;
  padding: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, .30);
  background: #fff;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#popup .close-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  right: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #111;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

#popup.active {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
<div id="popup">
  <label for="txtName">UserName:</label>
  <input type="text" id="txtName" class="form-control mb-2">
  <label for="txtAddress">Address:</label>
  <input type="text" id="txtAddress" class="form-control mb-2">
  <label for="txtPhone">Phone Number:</label>
  <input type="text" id="txtPhone" class="form-control mb-4">
  <button id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Save</button>
  <button href="" class="close-btn" onclick="toggle()">&times;</button>
</div>
<a class="primary-btn order-submit" style="cursor : pointer" onclick="toggle()" id="btnOpenPopup">Add New Address</a>



Blur element:
    <div class="container" id="blur">
    <div id="overlay"></div>
        <h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>
        <p class="text-success">@ViewData["StatusMessage"]</p>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h4>Cập nhật thông tin tài khoản</h4>
                <hr />
                <dl class="row">
                    <dt class="col-sm-4">
                    Profile Detail:
@*                     <md-card-content>
                        <div class="user text-center">
                            <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-W2XryVdi-lA/U6tSAh3SsbI/AAAAAAAAFGY/ZHJiUEcR_Zs/w480-h480/avatar%2Bmaterial%2Bdesign.png" alt="user avatar" class="user-avatar" />
                            <md-button class="md-icon-button user-avatar-edit" ng-click="browserAvatar()">
                                <md-icon class="text-center">photo_camera</md-icon>
                            </md-button>
                        </div>
                    </md-card-content> *@
                </dt>
                  
                    <dd class="col-sm-8">
                        <dl class="row">
                            <dt class="col-sm-6">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => Model.profile.UserName)</dt>
                        <dd class="col-sm-6">
                            @if (Model.profile.UserName == null)
                            {
                                <span class="empty-italic">empty</span>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <span>@Model.profile.UserName</span>
                            }
                        </dd>
                        </dl>
                        <dl class="row">
                            <dt class="col-sm-6">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => Model.profile.UserEmail)</dt>
                            <dd class="col-sm-6">@Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.profile.UserEmail)</dd>
                        </dl>
                        <dl class="row">
                            <dt class="col-sm-6">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => Model.profile.PhoneNumber)</dt>
                        <dd class="col-sm-6">
                            @if (Model.profile.PhoneNumber == null)
                            {
                                <span class="empty-italic">empty</span>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <span>@Model.profile.PhoneNumber</span>
                            }
                        </dd>
                        </dl>
                        <dl class="row">
                            <dt class="col-sm-6">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => Model.profile.HomeAdress)</dt>
                        <dd class="col-sm-6">
                            @if (Model.profile.HomeAdress == null)
                            {
                                <span class="empty-italic">empty</span>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <span>@Model.profile.HomeAdress</span>
                            }
                        </dd>
                        </dl>
                        <dl class="row">
                            <dt class="col-sm-6">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => Model.profile.BirthDate)</dt>
                        <dd class="col-sm-6">
                            @if (Model.profile.BirthDate == null)
                            {
                                <span class="empty-italic">empty</span>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <span>@Model.profile.BirthDate</span>
                            }
                        </dd>
                        </dl>
                        <a asp-action="EditProfile" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Edit</a>
                    </dd>
                </dl>

                <dl class="row">
                    <dt class="col-sm-4">Mật khẩu:</dt>
                    <dd class="col-sm-8">
                        @if (Model.HasPassword)
                        {
                            <a asp-controller="Manage" asp-action="ChangePassword" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Đổi mật khẩu</a>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <a asp-controller="Manage" asp-action="SetPassword" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Tạo mật khẩu</a>
                        }
                    </dd>
                </dl>

                <dl class="row">
                    <dt class="col-sm-4">Liên kết tài khoản ngoài:</dt>
                    <dd class="col-sm-8">
                        Có @Model.Logins.Count liên kết. <a asp-controller="Manage" asp-action="ManageLogins" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Quản lý liên kết ngoài</a>
                    </dd>
                </dl>

                <dl class="row">
                    <dt class="col-sm-4">Số điện thoại:</dt>
                    <dd class="col-sm-8">
                        <p>
                            Số điện thoại dùng để xác thực hai yếu tố
                        </p>
                        @(Model.PhoneNumber ?? "không có")
                        @if (Model.PhoneNumber != null)
                        {
                            <text>:</text>
                            <a asp-controller="Manage" asp-action="AddPhoneNumber" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning">Thay đổi</a>
                            <form asp-controller="Manage" asp-action="RemovePhoneNumber" method="post" role="form">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Loại bỏ số điện thoại</button>
                            </form>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <a asp-controller="Manage" asp-action="AddPhoneNumber" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Thêm số điện thoại</a>
                        }
                    </dd>
                </dl>

                <dl class="row">
                    <dt class="col-sm-4">Xác thực hai yếu tố:</dt>
                    <dd class="col-sm-8">
                        @if (Model.TwoFactor)
                        {
                            <form asp-controller="Manage" asp-action="DisableTwoFactorAuthentication" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                                (Đang kích hoạt) <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Hủy</button>
                            </form>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <form asp-controller="Manage" asp-action="EnableTwoFactorAuthentication" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Kích hoạt</button>
                            </form>
                        }
                    </dd>
                </dl>

                <dl class="row">
                    <dt class="col-sm-4">Xác thực ứng dụng:</dt>
                    <dd class="col-sm-8">
                        @if (Model.AuthenticatorKey == null)
                        {
                            <form asp-controller="Manage" asp-action="ResetAuthenticatorKey" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Phát sinh mã</button>
                            </form>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <p>Mã xác thực là: @Model.AuthenticatorKey</p>
                            <p>Nhập mã này khi yêu cầu xác thực 2 yếu tố</p>
                            <form asp-controller="Manage" asp-action="GenerateRecoveryCode" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Phát sinh mã phục hồi</button>
                            </form>
                        }
                    </dd>
                </dl>

            </div>
        <!-- Order Details -->
        <div class="col-md-5 order-details mt-lg-5" style="margin-left:90px;">

        
            <div class="section-title text-center">
                <h3 class="title">Sổ Địa Chỉ</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="order-summary">

                <div class="order-col">
                    <div><strong>PRODUCT</strong></div>
                    <div><strong>TOTAL</strong></div>
                </div>
                <div class="order-products">
                </div>
                <div class="order-col">
                    <div>Shiping</div>
                    <div><strong>FREE</strong></div>
                </div>
                <style>
                    #total {
                        white-space: nowrap; /* Ngăn chặn xuống dòng */
                    }
                </style>
                <div class="order-col">

                    <div><strong>DISCOUNT</strong></div>
                    <div><strong class="discount-total">0 VND</strong></div>

                </div>
                <div class="order-col">


                    <div><strong>TOTAL</strong></div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-checkbox" style="margin-top : 5px">
                <input type="checkbox" id="terms">
                <label for="terms">
                    <span></span>
                    I've read and accept the <a href="#">terms & conditions</a>
                </label>
            </div>
            <a class="primary-btn order-submit" style="cursor : pointer" onclick="toggle()" id="btnOpenPopup">Add New Address</a>
        </div>
        <!-- /Order Details -->
        </div>
    </div>

I notice when I scroll down the popup to the footer the popup tag turn to be like this img . Its seem like the popup transparent. Is there any way I can improve it?. Thank for your help

Can you add the "blur" element to your code? From the code provided it is not cleat what the issue is. Try adding the blur element, so that the code snippet replicates the issue.

When you give transparency to an element, everything inside that element becomes transparent. However, you cannot fix this by assigning no transparency to the descendants, because such an assignment will mean 100% of the transparency of the parent element, and it is already transparent. Therefore, you need to move the opaque elements out of the transparent ones.


function toggle() {
  var blur = document.getElementById('blur');
  blur.classList.toggle('active')
  var popup = document.getElementById('popup');
  popup.classList.toggle('active')
}
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap');
body {
  font: normal normal 14px/1.4 Roboto, sans-serif;
}

#btnOpenPopup {
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 20px 10px;
  width: min-content;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.container#blur {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/800/600);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: fixed;
  inset: -40px;
  z-index: -10;
}

.container#blur.active {
  filter: blur(20px);
  pointer-events: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#popup {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 600px;
}

#popup label {
  font-size: 90%;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

#popup input {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #D5D5D5;
}

#btnSave {
  margin-top: 2em;
  font: inherit;
  color: white;
  background-color: #337AB7;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 5px;
}

#btnSave:hover {
  background-color: #08d;
}

#btnOpenPopup {
  border-radius: 3px;
}

#btnOpenPopup:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: #08d;
}

#popup {
  position: fixed;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -20%);
  width: 600px;
  padding: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, .30);
  background: #fff;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#popup .close-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  right: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #111;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

#popup.active {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
<div class="container" id="blur">
</div>
<div id="popup">
  <label for="txtName">UserName:</label>
  <input type="text" id="txtName" class="form-control mb-2">
  <label for="txtAddress">Address:</label>
  <input type="text" id="txtAddress" class="form-control mb-2">
  <label for="txtPhone">Phone Number:</label>
  <input type="text" id="txtPhone" class="form-control mb-4">
  <button id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Save</button>
  <button href="" class="close-btn" onclick="toggle()">&times;</button>
</div>

<a class="primary-btn order-submit" style="cursor : pointer" onclick="toggle()" id="btnOpenPopup">Add New Address</a>




Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What did you change, and why?

Can I asked what different from my code ? or any elements you just add ?

@John The difference is the </div> in the 2nd line. That means the container MUST NOT contain anything because you are going to make it (and by definition everything it contains) transparent. To avoid making the popup transparent don't make it a child of container. (I also suggest calling container some other name like popup-overlay because it's weird for a container to not contain anything)
